# Does the retina MacBook Pro Australian charger duckhead have 3 prongs on it or 2?

Tags: macbook-pro, charger, macbook-pro-retina

I notice that with my Retina MacBook Pro (bought in UK), its charger uses all three prongs to power the laptop (like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jpQ2h.jpg), rather than [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bxnVN.jpg)). Not surprised, it's a powerful machine.

I'm going to Australia now and I want to use an aussie duckhead and make use of the innovative design. I have an existing one from an old iPod (and it used to work with fine with my MacBook Air when in australia), but it's only two prongs (like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fiCDR.jpg)).

Is that enough to power my rMBP? Or will it damage/strain it and I need to find a 3 prong one (if it even exists - I haven't bought my MBP in Australia) like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n0rMR.jpg)?

Comment: The prong missing is the earthing pin. I'd say it should work, since Apple's own plug for Australia is, as far as Google can tell (I don't own any), unearthed. This is not uncommon in Apple chargers. For instance, the Swiss plug that came with my MacBook Pro is unearthed.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance, after independent research on this it seems indeed that the official Apple 85W charger (at least i know from older mbp models using google image search) looks like it's only two prongs, so shall assume my existing 2 pronger duckhead is safe to use! Cheers...

Comment: Once you've made the trip Down Under and tested the charger you could answer your own question. Mark it as "Answered" for others to benefit from your experience. Have a nice trip!

Comment: @jaume great idea except to answer my own question I can only possibly go to an apple store in australia and ask someone there or open a packet and see. I'll try to do this :). the two pronger seems fine but again it isn't 100% peace of mind :). ongoing story!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YES, the Australian retina MacBook Pro charger duckhead IS two-prong. I verified it at an Australian licensed Apple reseller. 2-prong is perfectly fine.